# Has anyone setup SFTP with Google Cloud platform to trigger cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, sftp, edi

So I was able to setup SFTP so that I'm able to send a file to my VM instance on GCP.

However, does anyone have any guidance on how to then have a **cloud function** run at time of file being uploaded?

The objective is with our customers they send booking requests via SFTP in a certain EDI format.
Would need a cloud function to then run off of what was sent.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Google Cloud does not offer that feature. You could write a custom program implementing the **inotify** API and then do whatever you wanted such as calling a Cloud Function HTTP endpoint. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into inotify

Answer (score 2):

As an idea to think about - you might like to implement a SFTP server on a VM in a such manner that it uses Storage Buckets for file management behind the externally exposed standard API. In that case you may be able to use storage events to trigger cloud functions.

I think such implementations do exist, so it should be possible to find some examples.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I'll see what I can figure out. Anything I do, I'll make sure to let everyone here know

Answer (score 0):

So I could never figure out a simple, clean way of doing it on GCP. I did find this new platform called [stedi](https://stedi.com). I was able to resolve my needs by it.

DISCLAIMER: I am not affiliate with stedi in anyway. I just want others to know that its out there cause could save some developers some major headaches

Answer (score 0):

Building on @al-dann answer. You can map your VM folder to Google Cloud Storage Bucket and have cloud function triggered on file upload to Storage Bucket.

I found [sftpgo](https://github.com/drakkan/sftpgo) as one tool that is open source and works well for GCP.